# How to read the json file in spark using scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I want to read the JSON file in the below format:-

```
 {
  "titlename": "periodic",
    "atom": [
         {
          "usage": "neutron",
          "dailydata": [
    {
      "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:00:00Z",
      "datatimezone": "+02:00",
      "intervalvalue": 28128,
      "intervaltime": 15          
    },
    {
      "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:15:00Z",
      "datatimezone": "+02:00",
      "intervalvalue": 25687,
      "intervaltime": 15          
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am  writing my read line as:

```
sqlContext.read.json("user/files_fold/testing-data.json").printSchema
```

But I not getting the desired result-

```
root                                                                            
  |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Please help me on this

Comment: What Spark version do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access sub-entities in JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814926/how-to-access-sub-entities-in-json-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using `wholeTextFiles` to read the file and apply some functions to convert it to a single-line JSON format.

```
val json = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/files_fold/testing-data.json").
  map(tuple => tuple._2.replace("\n", "").trim)

val df = sqlContext.read.json(json)
```

You should have the final valid `dataframe` as

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|atom                                                                                                    |titlename|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|[[WrappedArray([+02:00,15,28128,2017-03-27T22:00:00Z], [+02:00,15,25687,2017-03-27T22:15:00Z]),neutron]]|periodic |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

And valid `schema` as

```
root
 |-- atom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: If I need to flatten this dataframe, how can it be acheived? simple `explode` is not working

Answer (score 3):

Spark 2.2 introduced multiLine option which can be used to load JSON (not JSONL) files:

```
spark.read
.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("/path/to/user.json")
```

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered nicely by other contributors, but I had one question which is how do i access each nested value/unit of the dataframe.

So, for collections, we can use explode and for struct types we can directly call the unit by `dot(.)`.

```
scala> val a = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("file:///home/hdfs/spark_2.json")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [atom: array<struct<dailydata:array<struct<datatimezone:string,intervaltime:bigint,intervalvalue:bigint,utcacquisitiontime:string>>,usage:string>>, titlename: string]

scala> a.printSchema
root
 |-- atom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)


scala> val b = a.withColumn("exploded_atom", explode(col("atom")))
b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [atom: array<struct<dailydata:array<struct<datatimezone:string,intervaltime:bigint,intervalvalue:bigint,utcacquisitiontime:string>>,usage:string>>, titlename: string ... 1 more field]

scala> b.printSchema
root
 |-- atom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)


scala>

scala> val c = b.withColumn("exploded_atom_struct", explode(col("`exploded_atom`.dailydata")))
c: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [atom: array<struct<dailydata:array<struct<datatimezone:string,intervaltime:bigint,intervalvalue:bigint,utcacquisitiontime:string>>,usage:string>>, titlename: string ... 2 more fields]

scala>

scala> c.printSchema
root
 |-- atom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)


scala> val d = c.withColumn("exploded_atom_struct_last", col("`exploded_atom_struct`.utcacquisitiontime"))
d: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [atom: array<struct<dailydata:array<struct<datatimezone:string,intervaltime:bigint,intervalvalue:bigint,utcacquisitiontime:string>>,usage:string>>, titlename: string ... 3 more fields]


scala> d.printSchema
root
 |-- atom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- titlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dailydata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- usage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- datatimezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- intervaltime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- intervalvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- utcacquisitiontime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_atom_struct_last: string (nullable = true)


scala> val d = c.select(col("titlename"), col("exploded_atom_struct.*"))
d: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [titlename: string, datatimezone: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> d.show
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|titlename|datatimezone|intervaltime|intervalvalue|  utcacquisitiontime|
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| periodic|      +02:00|          15|        28128|2017-03-27T22:00:00Z|
| periodic|      +02:00|          15|        25687|2017-03-27T22:15:00Z|
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

So thought of posting it here, in case if anyone has similar questions seeing this question.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with the JSON object stored inside your file, could you print it or make sure it's the one you provided in the question? I'm asking because I took that one and it runs just fine:

```scala
val json =
  """
    |{
    |  "titlename": "periodic",
    |  "atom": [
    |    {
    |      "usage": "neutron",
    |      "dailydata": [
    |        {
    |          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:00:00Z",
    |          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
    |          "intervalvalue": 28128,
    |          "intervaltime": 15
    |        },
    |        {
    |          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:15:00Z",
    |          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
    |          "intervalvalue": 25687,
    |          "intervaltime": 15
    |        }
    |      ]
    |    }
    |  ]
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.read
  .json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(json)))
  .printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apache Spark SQL Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object.

Thus,

```
{ "titlename": "periodic","atom": [{ "usage": "neutron", "dailydata": [ {"utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:00:00Z","datatimezone": "+02:00","intervalvalue": 28128,"intervaltime":15},{"utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:15:00Z","datatimezone": "+02:00", "intervalvalue": 25687,"intervaltime": 15 }]}]}
```

And then:

```
val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json("file")
jsonDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
[atom: array<struct<dailydata:array<struct<datatimezone:string,intervaltime:bigint,intervalvalue:bigint,utcacquisitiontime:string>>,usage:string>>, 
titlename: string]
```